# http error 500 when trying to insert date in to sql server 2008r2 using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Okay please bear with the fact that i am a total beginner when it comes to php.
I am trying to insert some values into my sql database (SQL Server 2008r2) but i keep getting the http error 500 (internal server error). I cant figure out what im doing wrong so maybe some of you guys can help out.

My connection.php:

```
<?php
try
{
    //connectie met sql-server, in dit geval met windows authenticatie
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Marcel;','','');  
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage();
    exit; 
}
?>
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="InsertBlogEntry.php">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Artikelnaam">Artikelnaam:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Artikelnaam" name="Artikelnaam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Artikelonderwerp">Artikelonderwerp</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Artikelonderwerp" name="Artikelonderwerp">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Artikeltext">Artikeltext</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="Artikeltext" rows="10" name="Artikeltext" style="resize: vertical;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="display: block; margin: auto;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My InsertBlogEntry.php:

```
<?php
    //set local time for $timeSubmitted
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');

    //define values
    $timeSubmitted = strftime('%A %d %B %Y om %H:%M',time());
    $Author = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $AtrikelNaam = $_POST['Artikelnaam'];
    $Onderwerp = $_POST['Artikelonderwerp'];
    $ArtkikelInhoud = $_POST['Artikeltext'];

    //include connection
    include ('connection.php');

    //statement
    $sql = sqlsrv_query("INSERT INTO BlogEntries (BlogTimeSubmitted, BlogAuthor, ArtikelName, ArtikelOW, ArtikelInhoud) VALUES ('$timeSubmitted', '$Author', '$AtrikelNaam', '$Onderwerp', '$ArtkikelInhoud')");

    //prepare and execute query
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($pdo, $sql);

     if($stmt)
     {
         echo 'succes';
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'failure';
        die (print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true))
     }

     //close connection
     sqlsrv_close($pdo);
?>
```

The table i am trying to insert the values in:

```
CREATE TABLE BlogEntries
(
ID int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
BlogTimeSubmitted datetime,
BlogAuthor varchar(64),
ArtikelName varchar(64),
ArtikelOW varchar (64),
ArtikelInhoud varchar(max)
);

//just for dropping the table
drop table BlogEntries

alter table BlogEntries
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BlogID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

I really hope some of you can help me with this problem, once again please be gentle as i am a total php beginner :)

**EDIT**

I have added some of my IIS logs below that might provide more information, i have tried analysing and googling them but i cant figure it out maybe some of you can:

```
2016-05-25 17:41:00 ::1 POST /marcel+website/InsertBlogEntry.php - 22926 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.102+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:22926/marcel%20website/AddBlogEntry.php 500 0 0 6

2016-05-25 17:41:00 ::1 POST /marcel+website/InsertBlogEntry.php - 22926 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.102+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:22926/marcel%20website/AddBlogEntry.php 500 0 0 8

2016-05-25 17:41:00 ::1 POST /marcel+website/InsertBlogEntry.php - 22926 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.102+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:22926/marcel%20website/AddBlogEntry.php 500 0 0 11
```

Comment: Anything in the logs?  Do other scripts / php code work connecting to the db ?

Comment: Look in the web servers error log. Also you are not using prepared statements. http://bobby-tables.com/ SQL injection

Comment: @Doon I'm not sure what log you mean (im very new to this) but i can access the db and show its contents on my pages without issues, i also have a working login that utilizes the database

Comment: your web server's error / access logs are where you will need to check. The 500 error is probably not with the code since normally php will throw that for a  code error. 500 error is pretty generic, so you need to look at the actual web server logs to see what the real error is...

Comment: @Doon i have updated the question with some of my IIS logs, also i have done some further testing and as far as i can tell the problem does not occur if i remover the if else statement in the InsertBlogEntrie.php

Comment: Well 500.0.0 is error with the isapi module. You might try enabling tracing (Google for it I am mostly an UNIX geek).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to comment on the 500 as that indicates something more serious in the PHP.

I've found that when working with MS SQL servers the **only** date format that works reliably is:

`YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss`

In PHP, that's

`%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S`

**Update:**
Looks like you're missing the `;` from your `die` line in the `else`.

Comment: ah okay, too bad you cant help with the 500 error but thanks for the tip regarding the date format!